# How to specify the CPU/RAM resources of Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have created a C# .NET Core Web API. I am using a Dockerfile and docker-compose to run the application. After my tests, I will publish it to Kubernetes.

So my problem is:

How can I specify the optimum CPU and memory limit needs of this application? And how many pods will I need actually? How can I measure and specify my needs?

Comment: Measure how much CPU and memory your application uses under load via load testing? Then specify something safely greater than that?

Comment: The only way to do this, is to perform extensive testing.  How well you app performs depends on many factors, the infrastructure it is running on will also play a significant part.  So you need to test, set the values, test again, adjust the values etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many resources a C# application needs and what I would do is give 1Gb of RAM and 1Cpu. Monitor the resources actually used over several days and then decide to lower or increase them. In any case, resources are not static values ​​and can be changed over time.

tl;dr

There is no precise answer for the question you asked because you have to have experience and understand what the application does and know what it needs.

Let's take some concrete examples.
In case the application is written in javascript and does nothing in particular then it is possible to keep the resources relatively low, for example 500Mi CPU and 500Mb Ram.
If this application uses more memory than expected or does a lot of calculations, you may consider increasing the limits.
In case this application is at the heart of the entire system, you might be thinking about standing higher with resources.

The advice I give you is to keep the pod limits in the production environment higher than in the development environment and check over time if these resources are sufficient or if it is necessary to increase them.

It is not always correct to significantly increase resources, sometimes it can be sufficient to increase the number of pods. In this case you can use HPA .
Once you have more data you can consider changing the resources and number of pods.

I personally prefer to have many pods with low resources rather than a few pods with high resources, but every application is different

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).